# 500 (Internal Server Error) For Ajax POST in Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel-5.1

Please can someone provide a simple example for ajax in laravel 5.1. I have tried everything and still no success. Tried the other solutions here but no luck, maybe it is my copy of laravel, I really don't understand. I just want to see how its done correctly. Please help me out. Thanks.

Route: `Route::post('/signin', 'UserController@ajax');`

```
<form action="signin" method="POST" id="form1">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

                <fieldset>

                    <p><label for="email">E-mail address</label></p>
                    <p><input type="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" onBlur="if(this.value=='')this.value='mail@address.com'" onFocus="if(this.value=='mail@address.com')this.value=''" name="email"></p> <!-- JS because of IE support; better: placeholder="mail@address.com" -->

                    <p><label for="password">Password</label></p>
                    <p><input type="password" name='password' value="password" onBlur="if(this.value=='')this.value='password'" onFocus="if(this.value=='password')this.value=''"></p> <!-- JS because of IE support; better: placeholder="password" -->

                    <p><input type="submit" value="Login" name="submit" id="sign"></p>

                </fieldset>

            </form>
```

for the controller:

```
    public function ajax(Request $request)
{
if(Request::ajax()) {
$data = Request::all();
print_r($data);
]);
     }
```

And ajax:

```
$('#sign').click(function(event) {

    $.ajaxSetup({
      headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token' : $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content') }
    });
    var inputs = $('#form1').serialize();

    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost/laravel/public/signin',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: inputs,
      success: function (data) {
          console.log(data);
      }
    })
    return false;

  });
```

Comment: If you get 500 Internal Server then the issue is not in Ajax, It is the problem in the Controller :)

Comment: May i see your code ?

Comment: Rather than look at one of our examples, why not post your own code and we can help you work through any problems.

Comment: I have provided a very simple code. Please take a look and see whats wrong